# How do I throw an exception in an Observable?

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-android

I'm trying to validate data so that I can throw an exception that will be specifically handled by the subscriber's onError, but I can't figure out how to throw the exception. This is current attempt:

```
Realm.getDefaultInstance()
        .asObservable()
        .map(new Func1<Realm, RealmResults<NewsFeed>>() {
            @Override
            public RealmResults<NewsFeed> call(Realm realm) {
                return realm.where(NewsFeed.class).findAll();
            }
        })
        .flatMap(new Func1<RealmResults<NewsFeed>, Observable<?>>() {
            @Override
            public Observable<?> call(RealmResults<NewsFeed> newsFeed) {
                if(newsFeed.size() == 0) {
                    // can't do this
                    return Observable.error(new NoDataException());
                }
                return newsFeed.first().asObservable();
            }
        });
```

This doesn't work because as far as I know, the observable stream must be homogeneous.

Answer (score 1):

Observable on the flatMap func1 should be Observable.

```
    Realm.getDefaultInstance()
            .asObservable()
            .map(new Func1<Realm, RealmResults<NewsFeed>>() {
                @Override
                public RealmResults<NewsFeed> call(Realm realm) {
                    return realm.where(NewsFeed.class).findAll();
                }
            })
            .flatMap(new Func1<RealmResults<NewsFeed>, Observable<NewsFeed>>() {
                @Override
                public Observable<NewsFeed> call(RealmResults<NewsFeed> newsFeed) {
                    if(newsFeed.size() == 0) {
                        return Observable.error(new NoDataException());
                    }
                    return newsFeed.first().asObservable();
                }
            })
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use the plain old Java throw statement there. Exceptions that are not handled within stream operators will be forwarded to the onError block of your subscriber.

```
Realm.getDefaultInstance()
    .asObservable()
    .map(new Func1<Realm, RealmResults<NewsFeed>>() {
        @Override
        public RealmResults<NewsFeed> call(Realm realm) {
            return realm.where(NewsFeed.class).findAll();
        }
    })
    .flatMap(new Func1<RealmResults<NewsFeed>, Observable<?>>() {
        @Override
        public Observable<?> call(RealmResults<NewsFeed> newsFeed) {
            if(newsFeed.size() == 0) {
                throw new NoDataException();
            }
            return newsFeed.first().asObservable();
        }
    });
```

Comment: I get an unhandled exception compile error when I throw an exception inside the call.

Comment: Hmm I'd guess that it probably has to do something with checked exceptions. Please try to subclass your exceptions from RunetimeException. If that fails to work too, please paste in the error you're seeing.